# Python hash() and equality behavior inconsistent with the Python documentation?

Tags: python, numpy

I cannot reconcile this in my mind:

```
x = 'U2'
import numpy
y = numpy.array("ab").dtype
```

But then

```
>>> x == y
True
>>> help(hash)
Help on built-in function hash in module builtins:

hash(obj, /)
    Return the hash value for the given object.

    Two objects that compare equal must also have the same hash value, but the
    reverse is not necessarily true.

>>> hash(x) == hash(y)
False
>>>
```

How am I misinterpreting what I'm seeing?

> Two objects that compare equal

```
>>> x == y
True
```

> must also have the same hash value

```
>>> hash(x) == hash(y)
False
```

How am I forgetting how *modus ponens* works?

Comment: Looks like a bug/oversight in numpy's dtype implementation to me.

Comment: You have not discovered a paradox. The documentation for hash is guidance that numpy is apparently disobeying.

Comment: Related issues on tracker:  [dype comparison with other types raise a TypeError](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1599#issuecomment-9618121), [dtype richcompare doesn't respect protocol](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5345)

Comment: What is there to reconcile? The `numpy` implementation for `__hash__` and `__eq__` is fundamentally broken for dtype objects.

Comment: In the duplicate the `dtype` object is compared to `np.float64` which is actually a function (a `type`).   Here 'U2' is a string.  But `np.dtype('U2')` is a dtype.  That's what's being compared with the `==`.  Maybe `dtype.__hash__` should be disabled.  I wonder if any thing/one uses it.  I wouldn't change the equality comparison.